# my website posts forms on http but not on https

Tags: forms, http, nginx, https

hello I'm in the process of converting my HTTP website to https but after getting https to work no post request from forms work

I have looked around a lot but nothing really describes what I have going on here, I doubt it nginx because when I start burp suite and make the website server HTTP it sends a post request like usual, but when I run it on https the post request isn't even sent doesn't show anything on the burp suite logs

```html
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <p><input type="text" name=username id="username">:username
    <p><input type="password" name=password id="password">:password
    <p><input type="checkbox" name = "rmbm" id="rmbm">
    <label for = "rmbm">remember me</label>
    <p><input type=submit value=Login>
    <a href = "\fp">forgot password?</a>
</form>
```

this is my form but I don't even see a post request

I should see a post request but I don't on burp sute

update:

hello, I've just had an epiphany. could it be the service worker and yes I was right after unregistering the service worker it worked perfectly so the problem is the service worker.

knowing this I will post the code

my service worker:

```
console.log('Hello from sw.js');


'use strict';

var cacheVersion = 1;
var currentCache = {
  offline: 'offline-cache' + cacheVersion
};

this.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(currentCache.offline).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
          '/static/html/offline.html',
          '/sw.js'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  console.log("fetching");
    if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' || (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
          event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request.url).catch(error => {
                // Return the offline page
                return caches.match('/static/html/offline.html');
            })
      );
    }
    else{
          event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request)
                          .then(function (response) {
                          return response || fetch(event.request);
                      })
              );
        }
  });
```

now looking at my code it just dosnt handle post request
so i will try to fix this on my own

Comment: can you open the browser developer console (F11/F12) and see what happens in the Browser.

Comment: I have, nothing, no errors just doesn't send the post request

Comment: Yep got it. That's tthe reason why you should open the developer console and see which errors you get in the browser